# How to Pass object/parameters to Testng

Tags: java, testng

I want to pass parameters to testng class.
I have a tc object with variables tc1.featureFileName, tc1.fieldValueMap

I have parsed the name to c2, but i don't know how to pass the
tc1.fieldValueMap which contains hashmap of input variables to testng.

```
        Class c2 = Class.forName("com.Scenarios."+tc1.featureFileName);

        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {c2});
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
```

Comment: though the question isn't very clear, yet http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample that shows you how to inject parameters as key/value pairs when you are using the TestNG APIs.

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.testng.xml.XmlTest;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        XmlSuite xmlSuite = new XmlSuite();
        xmlSuite.setName("Sample_Suite");
        Map<String, String> fieldValues = new ParamContainer().getValues();
        xmlSuite.setParameters(fieldValues);
        XmlTest xmlTest = new XmlTest(xmlSuite);
        xmlTest.setName("Sample_test");
        xmlTest.setXmlClasses(Collections.singletonList(new XmlClass(HelloWorld.class)));
        TestNG tng = new TestNG();
        tng.setXmlSuites(Collections.singletonList(xmlSuite));
        tng.run();
    }

    /**
     * This is a test class.
     */
    public static class HelloWorld {
        @Test
        @Parameters("name")
        public void hi(String name) {
            Assert.assertNotNull(name);
            Reporter.log("Name is:" + name, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Simulates a class that will contain all the key/value pairs that are to be used as
     * <code><parameters></code> for the suite.
     */
    public static class ParamContainer {
        private Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();

        ParamContainer() {
            values.put("name", "Jack-Daniel");
        }

        Map<String, String> getValues() {
            return values;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how does this relate to the question above? I don't see an XML suite in use by the OP.

Comment: The question is about feeding in a bunch of key value pairs into a test execution when using TestNG APIs. And the sample shows how to do that.

Comment: The question also pertains to another way of doing that and the sample just dumps in some other way. It better be a comment to a project link in such case. There can be N ways of solving a problem, but if you post X as an answer to the question related to A. That wouldn't help.

Comment: @nullpointer - There is no xml involved by the OP. TestNG doesn't let you pass in parameters when there's no xml involved. The sample I shared provides for this by creating an xml suite programatically.

Comment: OP starts off the question with this **I want to pass parameters to testng class** and the sample shows exactly that. I

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Appreciate your help, is there a way where i can send a complete object ex.    tc that can contain other values like filename and tc name?                                      tc1.testcaseName
tc1.featureFileName
tc1.fieldValueMap  this will be useful in creating logs.

Comment: @spartycurse - You can only pass in Key/Value pairs as `String` if you are going to use the `<parameter>` approach. But if you want to inject complex objects etc., you would need to basically do it via the `ITestResult.setAttribute` of the particular test method (Common way of doing this would be to inject this via the `IInvokedListener#beforeInvocation()`. Please post it as a separate question.